# CKEditor entermode issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ckeditor, fckeditor

On demo page of Ckeditor please type in source mode for example :

Default entermode is : "P"

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>Hello</p>
```

After this, in standard mode add new line before "Hello" word and then press backspace...
Chrome will add span tag for this (But it should not)...Other browsers works fine.

When i change entermode to "BR" it works fine in chrome too...It's fine for me, but 
is there any way to override "BR" entermode to have double new lines when enter key is pressed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is Webkits' terrible behaviour. When you press backspace it creates that `span` to preserve styles of the 1st line when 2nd line (header) is merged with it. Unfortunately this cannot be fixed in other way than by CKEditor core devs, because most likely only custom backspace handler will prevent that.

I added your case to this ticket: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998

Comment: Has there been any progress on this issue?

Comment: None. Neither Webkit's nor Blink's developers responded. We can't wait forever, so we're definitely going to fix this on our side. Although, we've got other priorities now, so this ticket has to wait. Can't do anything about this :(.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to use the `Remove Format` button. When you notice this occurring, highlight the altered text and clicking the `Remove Format` button will remove the injected span. Not a fix, but at least it becomes manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin to fix this Bug.. in the init() Callback:

http://pastebin.com/S0epuBNA